# How to set multiple Out variable value from single Select Query From Store Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_search_dir`(
IN name varchar(50),
OUT employeeId varchar(50) ,
OUT employeeName varchar(50)
)

BEGIN


 -- First : working ---
 SELECT  EAE.id INTO employeeId , EAE.name INTO employeeName 
 FROM employeesDB.employee AS EAE
 WHERE EAE.f_name  LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%');


 -- Second Working ---
 SELECT  EAE.id INTO employeeId , EAE.name INTO employeeName 
 FROM employeesDB.employee AS EAE
 WHERE EAE.f_name  LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%');

 -- Third  NOT working  getting syntax ERROR why i am not able to set two 
 OUT variable in one select  

 SELECT  
 EAE.id INTO employeeId ,
 EAE.name INTO employeeName 
 FROM employeesDB.employee AS EAE
 WHERE EAE.f_name  LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%');

 END
```

I am not  able to set the  multiple out value in single select query inside the store-procedure  to get the id and employeename i have to call the two select query i want to extract the result in one query..

Answer (score 1):

You got the [SELECT ... INTO](http://%20https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) syntax wrong.

It must be:

```
SELECT EAE.id, EAE.name
     INTO employeeId, employeeName 
 FROM employeesDB.employee AS EAE
 WHERE EAE.f_name LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%');
```

Comment: THanks but  i want to  set the value in the out variable

Comment: Yes we are setting the 2 out variables `employeeId` and `employeeName`  in my answer. Is it not working on your side?